# Is there any way to launch a live VBA command line in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

To write and edit VBA macros in Excel currently, I am pressing the "Macros" menu button, entering a name for my macro, and then writing it in an editor window where the code for all my macros is. I can run it with the "run" button.

Is it possible to get a live VBA "shell" instead, sort of a window or command prompt where you just enter VBA lines of code one at a time, noticing the effect of each line immediately, just like coding in a live Python shell?

Comment: You can use the Immediate window in the vb editor for that.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find this window in Excel. The Microsoft documentation says it can be found in the View menu or by pressing CTRL-G. CTRL-G brings up a "Go to Cell" window for me, and I don't see the Immediate window in the View menu. Do you know why this is? Thank you

Comment: You should press `Ctrl + G` **being in VBE (Visual Basic Editor)**. `Alt + F11`...

Comment: Got it; thx very much.

Comment: I tried "Dim source As Workbook" and received "Compile Error: Invalid in Immediate Pane". Would you know why variable type declaration would be invalid in the immediate pane?

Comment: The immediate window can only execute lines. You can't define variables.

Comment: Thanks. After more experimentation I found that it does not return this error if I define the variable type, then assign it an object, like Set source = ThisWorkbook. @FunThomas, you say you can only "execute lines". What is the difference between a line and defining a variable? I.e., how to know which kinds of commands are permitted and which not? Thank you very much.

Comment: Following up on this - I did find documentation that you can run Subs and Functions from the immediate window. But I still dont understand its behavior fully. For example, why do I get a compile error if I declare a variable type inside Sub name() and End Sub commands? Does VBA throw an error if a variable is declared but unused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already given in the comments: Use the *Immediate Window*. It is part of the VBE environment, not part of Excel (or Word or any other environment using VBA). To show it, use View->Immediate Window, or the shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>G</kbd>

What you can do in the Immediate Window:

**(1)** Execute any VBA statement:

- Call a Subroutine or Function: `MyMacro 1, 2`
- Change the content of a variable: `i = 123`,
- modify something in the underlying Application: `ActiveCell.Interior.Color = vbRed`

You can execute any statement that is *executable*. Statements like `Dim` and `Option` are not executable. Try to set a breakpoint to a statement: If you can't, the statement is not executable (not 100% true: You can set a breakpoint at the `Sub`-statement but can't create a Sub in the immediate window).

**(2)** Show the value of a simple data type (numbers, strings, dates...).  Preceed a question mark:

- `? "Hello World"`
- `? i`
- `? MyFunction(3)`

If you want your code to write something to the immediate windows, use the statement `Debug.Print`.

---

What you need to understand is the *context* in which the statement is running:

If your code is in **break mode** (a macro is running and either hit a breakpoint, an assert statement or when a runtime error occured and you pressed the "Debug"-Button), the context is the context of the actual macro. If the macro declares a variable, the immediate window accesses this variable. If the module is using global variables, the immediate window can access them also.

If, however, no macro is currently running (and was interrupted), the immediate window uses it's own context. You can create variables in this context by simply assigning a value to it, like `meaningOfLife = 42` or `Set ws = ActiveSheet`, they are created as `Variant`. Basically, think of the context as if you have a blank module without `Option Explicit`. Just be aware that those variables are not available to any of your other macros.

My experience is that if you want to execute more that one statement, it's easier to create a small test subroutine - if you want to have it clean, you can create an own module for that. You can then call this test subroutine from the immediate window.

Comment: Thanks. I'll study this answer deeper. Right now what I am finding is that the Immediate Window allows you to enter some code and to execute it. But it's not quite like a Python live shell. Because the same command you entered remains after execution. In a way, its still just a place for pre-writing scripts or functions and executing them, just a little faster than the normal macro editor window. I'm curious, is this the only option, or is there any other option more like a live shell? I guess if I just deleted each command afterwards it would be like a shell, since you say the context stays.

Comment: I would not compare the I.W. to a Python shell or a browser console. There are some similarities, but some things are different. No, you don't write scripts in the I.W., you just execute a command. And then maybe the next. You can repeat a command by putting the cursor to the line and press Enter. No need to ever delete anything from the I.W., except for optical reasons.

Comment: Fyi The immediate window even allows to code loops within one-liners separated by `:` - e.g. `For i = 1 to 5:? i;:Next` @FunThomas